# Loop embedded youtube player

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I want to loop or even stop an embedded youtube video but it doesn't seem to work. Currently other videos play after the one and I'm trying to prevent that. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<iframe width="450" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gNWKnkxbCOA?rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=gNWKnkxbCOA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I just inserted that code into a random website and it works just fine for me. When the video is over it restarts.

Comment: This works on Chrome, but hangs the browser on Internet Explorer 9 and firefox. I'm having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204786/looping-through-multiple-youtube-videos-in-wpf